# Unable to up cvat_server

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am running opencv cvat on local machine , using docker command to up -> docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up, all the containers are getting up successfully except cvat_server.

getting bellow response on docker terminal for cvat_server

```
2024-01-19 21:10:21 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:10:21 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
2024-01-19 21:11:21 wait-for-it.sh: waiting for cvat_db:5432 without a timeout
2024-01-19 21:11:21 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:11:21 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
2024-01-19 21:12:22 wait-for-it.sh: waiting for cvat_db:5432 without a timeout
2024-01-19 21:12:22 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:12:22 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
2024-01-19 21:13:22 wait-for-it.sh: waiting for cvat_db:5432 without a timeout
2024-01-19 21:13:22 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:13:22 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
2024-01-19 21:14:22 wait-for-it.sh: waiting for cvat_db:5432 without a timeout
2024-01-19 21:14:22 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:14:22 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
2024-01-19 21:15:23 wait-for-it.sh: waiting for cvat_db:5432 without a timeout
2024-01-19 21:15:23 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:15:23 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
2024-01-19 21:16:23 wait-for-it.sh: waiting for cvat_db:5432 without a timeout
2024-01-19 21:16:23 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:16:23 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
2024-01-19 21:17:24 wait-for-it.sh: waiting for cvat_db:5432 without a timeout
2024-01-19 21:17:24 wait-for-it.sh: cvat_db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
2024-01-19 21:17:24 /usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNO6k.png)

I am trying on windows 11 machine , run wsl command as well.
Due to above mentioned issue i am unable to run opencv cvat on local machine

[below are the link of two docker-compose file which i am using to up server on my local machine]

https://github.com/opencv/cvat/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml
https://github.com/opencv/cvat/blob/develop/docker-compose.dev.yml

Comment: `python3\r` suggests your file incorrectly has DOS line endings, but it's running in a Linux container.

Comment: @DavidMaze How i can fix this issue? 
Note - I am working on windows 11, i run dos2unix command as well.

Comment: Please include your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Sure @datawookie, Added above.